# Flink: What is the best way to summarize the result from all partitions

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The datastream is partitioned and distributed to each slot for processing. Now I can get the result of each partitioned task. What is the best approach to apply some function to those result of different partitions and get a global summary result?

Updated:
I want to implement some data summary algorithm such as Misra-Gries in Flink. It will maintain k counters and update with data arriving. Because data may be large scalable, It's better that each partition has its own k counters and process parallel. Finally merge those counters to final k counters to present the result. What is the best way to do combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink's built-in aggregation functions, like `reduce`, `sum`, and `max` are built on top of Flink's managed keyed state mechanism, and can only be applied to a `KeyedStream`. What you can do, however, is use either [`WindowAll`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#keyed-vs-non-keyed-windows) or [`ProcessFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html). Here is an example:

```
parallelStream
  .process(new MyProcessFunction())
  .setParallelism(1)
  .print()
  .setParallelism(1);
```

Note that all of the preliminary processing is being done at the default parallelism, and then the process function and print are being applied serially.

The `ProcessFunction` should keep its state in [managed operator (non-keyed) state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-managed-operator-state) in order to be fault tolerant.

This will produce a continuously updated stream of summaries over the entire input. Use something like `countWindowAll` or `timeWindowAll` if you prefer to produce summaries over windows.

Comment: After my first operator, I get updated summary stream of multiple partition. How can I keep picking up the newest item in each partition and apply a function on those item? For example, if i have a parallelism of 2, after a map operator, I will get two partitioned summary stream(1,2,3,4,5...), (7,8,9,10,11...). How can I fetch the newest item of each stream and calculate their sum as a new stream? Such as(1+7, 2+8, 3+9, 3+10, 4+10, 4+11, 5+11....) like that? I don't know if I describe clearly sorry……

Comment: For that specific case, you could, for example, use a RichCoFlatMap or a CoProcessFunction to implement such a zipper-like merging sum. The items from each partition would remain in order, but one stream might fall behind the other, so you'd have to buffer elements in a queue until the matching element arrives from the other partition.

Comment: Note that if the stream is organized by a key, then you could do something simpler, using reduce, or sum. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/index.html#datastream-transformations.

Comment: That helps me a a lot! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry another question. If the previous operator's parallelism is 2 and current one is 1. When a data item come in, can I get which partition(instance) it come from?

Comment: In a RichFunction you can use getRuntimeContext().getIndexOfThisSubtask() to get the current partition. You could use this in the previous operator to enhance each record with the partition number, and use this downstream.

Comment: BTW, if you were to edit your question to better explain what you're trying to do, then I could update my answer accordingly, and others would have a better chance of finding and benefiting from this interaction.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question I hope it can be clear? Thank you very much! BTW your method is a solution which can help me a lot. Thank you!