# Is there any reference of Misra-Gries Implementation in apache-flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I want to implement Misra-Gries algorithm in apache flink. But unable think of distributed MapState usage. Any reference would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flink: What is the best way to summarize the result from all partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842618/flink-what-is-the-best-way-to-summarize-the-result-from-all-partitions)

Comment: I tried to implement it after going through the above link but still stuck . I want something like this. If whole input is like 1,3,4,2,3,1,5,6,3,3 -> considering 2 parallel task execution stream through => node1(1,4,1,5,3)  => output [(1,2),(4,1),(3,1),(5,1)]. Through node2(3,2,6,3,3) => [(3,3),(2,1),(6,1)]. Then I want to merge these two outputs and finally I will get [(1,2),(4,1),(3,4),(5,1),(2,1),(6,1)]. I used RichFlatMapFunction and CheckpointedFunction. When I collect it gives me List of tuples where I want only 2 lists of tuples.